# ¿Cómo ordenar un vector de menor a mayor en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando la manera de que funcione mi comparador para obtener un listado ordenado de **menor a mayor**. Este es mi código:

```
function ordenarMenAMay(vector) {
  let aux = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < vector.length - 1; j++) {
      if (vector[i] > vector[j + 1]) {
        aux = vector[j];
        vector[j] = vector[j + 1];
        vector[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Da un vistazo a https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy

Answer (score 5):

Para entender el problema, primero hay que entender la lógica de tu ordenamiento.

---

Este ordenamiento se le conoce como *ordenamiento burbuja*, que es un ordenamiento muy conocido. Sabemos muy bien que `i` y `j` son índices diferentes para iterar sobre el array original. `i` se usa para iterar sobre cada elemento del array, mientras que `j` se usa para comparar cada elemento con su siguiente.

---

Ahora, mira esta comparación:

```
if (vector[i] > vector[j + 1]) { ... }
```

aquí comparas **el elemento** `vector[i]` con **el siguiente elemento** `vector[j + 1]`, de lo cual estaría incorrecto, ya que `i` y `j + 1` apuntan a dos elementos diferentes del array.

*Recuerda lo que dije antes, `i` y `j` **son índices diferentes**.*

Entonces, necesitamos comparar el elemento `vector[j]` actual con su siguiente elemento **del mismo índice**, que es `vector[j + 1]`, por lo que la condicional quedaría así:

```
if (vector[j] > vector[j + 1]) { ... }
```

Y con esto ya lo tendrías.

---

**Demo:**

```js
function ordenarMenAMay(vector) {
  let aux = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < vector.length - 1; j++) {
      if (vector[j] > vector[j + 1]) {
        aux = vector[j];
        vector[j] = vector[j + 1];
        vector[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return vector;
}

let array = [6, 5, 1, 8, 2];
console.log("Array original:", array);

let result = ordenarMenAMay(array);
console.log("Array ordenado:", result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function ordenarMenAMay( vector ) {
  let aux = 0;
  let desordenado = true;
  while( desordenado ) {        
    desordenado = false;
    for( let i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++ ) {
      if( vector[ i ] > vector[ i + 1 ] ) {
        aux = vector[ i ];
        vector[ i ] = vector[ i + 1 ];
        vector[ i + 1 ] = aux;
        desordenado = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return vector;
}

let array = [ 6, 5, 1, 8, 2 ];
console.log( "Array original:", array );

let result = ordenarMenAMay( array );
console.log( "Array ordenado:", result );
```

Esta respuesta la podríamos considerar como una ampliación de la de @Cris223511.dev, de hecho copié casi todo su código (espero que no se de cuenta), solo que la forma en que implementaste el algoritmo de la burbuja, no es la más óptima, dado que, aunque reciba un `array` ordenado, iterará todas la veces que le indican las condiciones de los for (creo que n*n), con esta pequeña modificación, si el `array` se ordena antes, no se entra en el `if`, por o que **desordenado** queda **false**, se retorna el `array` y sale de la función.

Después de leer la excelente optimización de @Anibal Cabeza, no puedo no "robarle" su optimización y pegarla a la mía, para obtener lo mejor de ambas:

```js
function ordenarMenAMay( vector ) {
  let aux = 0;
  let desordenado = true;
  let lon = vector.length -1;
  while( desordenado ) {        
    desordenado = false;
    for( let i = 0; i < lon; i++ ) {
      if( vector[ i ] > vector[ i + 1 ] ) {
        aux = vector[ i ];
        vector[ i ] = vector[ i + 1 ];
        vector[ i + 1 ] = aux;
        desordenado = true;
      }
    }
    lon -= 1;
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Ahora mi respuesta pasa a ser una ampliación de las de los dos... espero que el OP, no de por aceptada la mía... sería injusto.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, no cometiste ningún error, tu respuesta es correcta, cuando puse "la forma en que implementaste el algoritmo de la burbuja, no es la más óptima", me estaba dirigiendo al OP, por eso dije que mi respuesta es más una ampliación de la tuya que una respuesta... lo que si no te voy a perdonar, es que no me hayas pegado un buen reto por el comentario que puse (y que después borré)... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ampliando un poco la respuesta de Cris (que está perfecta), se puede hacer un poco mas ágil la función si pensamos que, mientras se va ordenando, se va cometiendo redundancia de comparaciones. Un ejemplo:

imagina un vector 1, 6, 7, 4, 3
la ejecución haría estas comparaciones:

```
1>6, 6>7, 7>4, 7>3 == 1, 6, 4, 3, 7
1>6, 6>4, 6>3, 6>7 == 1, 4, 3, 6, 7
1>4, 4>3, 4>6, 4>7 == 1, 3, 4, 6, 7
1>3, 3>4, 4>6, 6>7 == 1, 3, 4, 6, 7
```

Podemos ver que se realizan comparaciones innecesarias porque el ciclo si o si recorre todo el vector en cada vuelta. En cada vuelta el iterador lleva el mayor al ultimo indice pero sigue comparando indices ya ordenados.
Si quisiéramos modificar eso basta con restar el indice i en el ciclo de j.
El mismo ejemplo haria esto:

```
1>6, 6>7, 7>4, 7>3 == 1, 6, 4, 3, 7
1>6, 6>4, 6>3 == 1, 4, 3, 6, 7
1>4, 4>3 == 1, 3, 4, 6, 7
1>3 == 1, 3, 4, 6, 7
```

fijate como en cada vuelta hace menos comparaciones. La función mejorada quedaría así:

```
function ordenarMenAMay(vector) {
  let aux = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < vector.length - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (vector[j] > vector[j + 1]) {
        aux = vector[j];
        vector[j] = vector[j + 1];
        vector[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return vector;
}
```

Espero te ayude